# Finding spots in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the following Matrix made of 0s and 1s which I want to identify its spots(elements with the value 1 and connected to eachothers).

```
M = np.array([[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
              [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
              [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]])
```

In the matrix there are four spots.

an example of my output should seem the following

```
spot_0 = array[(0,0),(0,1), (0,2), (1,0),(1,1), (1,2), (2,0),(2,1), (2,2), (3,0),(3,1), (3,2)]
Nbr_0 = 12
Top_Left = (0, 0)
and that is the same process for the other 3 spots
```

Does anyone know how can I identify each spot with the number of its elements and top_left element, using numpy functions ?
Thanks

Comment: How would "identifying" a spot look like? Printing it's x and y coordinates?

Comment: Its order, its first element (Top_Left), its elements and their number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `skimage.measure.label` or other tools (for instance, `OpenCV` or `igraph`) to create labels for connected components:

```
#from @Jérôme's answer
from skimage.measure import label
components = label(M)

# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]])
```

In the later part you could create a one-dimensional view of image, sort values of pixels and find dividing points of sorted label values:

```
components_ravel = components.ravel()
c = np.arange(1, np.max(components_ravel) + 1)
argidx = np.argsort(components_ravel)
div_points = np.searchsorted(components_ravel, c, sorter=argidx)

# Sorted label values are:
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
# 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
# 2, 2, 2, 2
# 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
# 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
# So you find indices that divides these groups:
# [47, 59, 63, 79]
```

After that you could split array of indices that sorts your one-dimensional view of image at these points and convert them into two-dimensional ones:

```
spots = []
for n in np.split(argidx, div_points)[1:]: #in case there are no zeros, cancel `[1:]`
    x, y = np.unravel_index(n, components.shape)
    spots.append(np.transpose([x, y]))
```

It creates a list of spot coordinates of each group:

```
[array([[1, 0], [1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0], [2, 2], [2, 1], [2, 0], [3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0]]),
 array([[2, 10], [1, 9], [2, 9], [1, 10]]),
 array([[6, 5], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7], [6, 7], [6, 6], [3, 5], [4, 6], [3, 6], [4, 5], [3, 7], [5, 7], [5, 6], [4, 7], [5, 5], [5, 4]]),
 array([[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [6, 2], [7, 0], [6, 0], [6, 1], [7, 1], [7, 2]])]
```

Note that an order of pixels of each group is mixed. This is because `np.argsort` uses a sort which is not stable. You could fix it like so:

```
argidx = np.argsort(components_ravel, kind='stable')
```

In this case you'll get:

```
[array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2]]),
 array([[1, 9], [1, 10], [2, 9], [2, 10]]),
 array([[3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7]]),
 array([[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [6, 0], [6, 1], [6, 2], [7, 0], [7, 1], [7, 2]])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a connected component labeling to find the spots. Then, you can use `np.max` so to find the number of component and `np.argwhere` so to find the locations of each component. Here is an example:

```py
# OpenCV provides a similar function
from skimage.measure import label

components = label(M)
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
#        [4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]])

for i in range(1, np.max(components)+1):
    spot_i = np.argwhere(components == i)
    Nbr_i = len(spot_i)
    Top_Left_i = spot_i[0]
```

Note that `Top_Left` only make sense for a *rectangular area*. If they are not rectangular this point needs to be carefully defined.

Note also that this method is only efficient with few component. If there are many component, then it is better to replace the current loop by an iteration over the `components` array (in this case the output structure is stored in a list `l` and `l[components[i,j]]` is updated with the information found for all item location `(i,j)` of `components`). This last algorithm will be slow unless Numba/Cython are used to speed the process up.

Comment: I think it should be `range(1, np.max(components) + 1)`. This is simple and nice solution, by the way. After you find components, it's `O(nm)` where `n` is a size of image and `m` is a number of components. I thinks it's possible to improve up to`O(n log n + m log n)` using `np.argsort` + `np.searchsort`

Comment: @mathfux Indeed for the +1. I missed this (now edited). Thank you. For the optimization, the provided code indeed runs in `O(nm)` time, but the last section of the answer provides a `O(n)` solution since `label` should run in `O(n)` and the alternative loop does constant-time fetches.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Is there a simple way to implement it in `O(n)` in `numpy`? The best that I could do was `O(n log n)` on `np.argsort` plus `O(m log n)` on identifying `m` groups of sorted variant of pixels of image. Also, what's the alternative way of `OpenCv`?